# How to use AWS Lambda to get prints when they ready?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I'm trying to use AWS Lambda to get prints when they are ready.
For example if the function return `print1` and after 2 seconds it will return `print2`, it will first print to the user `print1` and after 2 seconds the user will get `print 2`.

I'm calling my function using Lambda function URL with stream option enable.

This is the code I'm testing, but it print everything when everything it's ready and not one by one:

```
const handleInternal = async (_event, responseStream, _context) => {
  responseStream.setContentType("text/plain");
 
  const sentences = [
    "print 1",
    "print 2",
    "print 3",
  ]
 
  const timer = ms => new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, ms));
 
  for(let i = 0; i < sentences.length; i++) {
    responseStream.write(`${sentences[i]}\n`);
    await timer(2000);
  }
 
  responseStream.end();
 }
 
 exports.handler = awslambda.streamifyResponse(handleInternal);
```